# How do you initialize properties with custom setters that do error checking?

Tags: kotlin

How can I initialize a property with a custom setter?

For example, in my setter I make sure that the value is not negative.

```
class Foo(length: Int) {
    var length = length
        set(value) {
            if (value < 0) throw IllegalArgumentException("Can't be negative.")
            field = value
        }
    }
}
```

However if I call it as `Foo(-5)` the exception doesn't call since setters aren't called when properties are initialized.

Another thing I tried was below, but then it seems wrong to set the length twice.

```
class Foo(length: Int) {
    var length = length
        set(value) {
            if (value < 0) throw IllegalArgumentException("Can't be negative.")
            field = value
        }
    }

    init {
        this.length = length
    }
}
```

Finally I thought about the code below, but that seems wrong since you are checking for the wrong value in two spots.

```
class Foo(length: Int) {
    init {
        if (length < 0) throw IllegalArgumentException("Can't be negative.")
    }

    var length = length
        set(value) {
            if (value < 0) throw IllegalArgumentException("Can't be negative.")
            field = value
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second method is just about as clean as you can make it, although I would set the initial value to some constant like 0 rather than `length`. Then if you forget to assign `length` in an `init` block, you get a compiler warning that the constructor parameter is unused.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a 'fourth' way (variation of your second, actually):

```
class Foo {
    var length = 0 // You cannot even assign length here
        set(value) {
            if (value < 0) throw IllegalArgumentException("Can't be negative.")
            field = value
        }

    // Having to use a warning suppression is the primary drawback of this 'fourth' way
    @Suppress("ConvertSecondaryConstructorToPrimary")
    constructor(length: Int) {
        this.length = length
    }
}
```

Apart from the express warning suppression annotation, this way the cleanest in my opinion, with no repetition and with minimal boilerplate.